# UrlSplitResult: can't _replace fields

Tags: python, urllib, namedtuple

I'm trying to inject a basic-authentication into an url by split-inject-join:

```py
    url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    new_url = url._replace(username=user, password=password)
```

But I'm surprised about the behavior of the `SplitResult` I get from the `urllib.parse.urlsplit` method:

```py
>>> v = urlsplit('http://a.b/c/d')
>>> v.username is None and v.password is None  # None, but accessible
True
>>> v._replace(scheme='ftp')  # beautiful!  Just like expected.
SplitResult(scheme='ftp', netloc='a.b', path='/c/d', query='', fragment='')

# however...
>>> v._replace(scheme='ftp', username='u', password='p')
...ValueError: Got unexpected field names: ['username', 'password']
```

It seems as if the `None` fields in this `SplitResult` can not be replaced.  This is odd, since [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) claims it to *be* a named tuple.

When I do the equivalent with a self-constructed named tuple, it appears that the 'None' fields *can* be replaced without problem.

```py
>>> T = namedtuple("T", ("a", "b", "c"))
>>> t = T(a=1, b=2, c=None)
>>> t
T(a=1, b=2, c=None)
>>> t._replace(c=3)
T(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

But the same exception can be triggered by replacing an unexisting field.

```py
>>> t._replace(d=4)  # should raise, please
...ValueError: Got unexpected field names: ['d']
# I was expecting an AttributeError, but hey...
```

However, in this case, the unexpected field is really not accessible:

```py
>>> t.d is None
...AttributeError: 'T' object has no attribute 'd'
```

Any idea what makes the `SplitResult` different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn't list indices for the fields `username`, `password`, `hostname`, or `port`. This suggests they aren't actually part of the namedtuple, but instead are just attributes of the `SplitResult` object. Looking in the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3fee7776e6ed8ab023a0220da1daf3160fda868b/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L323), it seems like `SplitResult` inherits from both the namedtuple containing the first few fields which have indices, as well as a mixin which adds the other fields as [properties](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3fee7776e6ed8ab023a0220da1daf3160fda868b/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L148).